# Proper format of IP address list for Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file

I am creating a Terraform config to deploy an Application Gateway in Azure that will sit in front of an App Service Environment (ASE) that is configured to use an internal load balancer.  I run my terraform configs from Azure Cloud Shell using shell scripts.  In the shell script I am running AZ CLI commands to acquire the IP address of the ASE internal load balancer and then I feed that into my Terraform config as a command line variable.  I keep getting an error that says ip_address_list should be a list but I am unsure what format that means.

Below is the command I am using to grab the IP address:

```
ilbase_virtual_ip=$(
  az resource show \
  --ids "/subscriptions/$subscription_id/resourceGroups/$ilbase_rg_name/providers/Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments/$ilbase_name/capacities/virtualip" \
  --query "additionalProperties.internalIpAddress"
)
```

This returns the IP address formatted as below.  I am echo'ing it out as part of the shell script so I can verify that it was successfully acquired:

`"10.10.1.11"`

Below is the Terraform command line I am using in my shell script:

```
terraform plan \
  -var "tfstate_access_key=$tfstate_storage_access_key" \
  -var "ilbase_virtual_ip=$ilbase_virtual_ip"
```

Below is the code from my Terraform config where I am trying to apply the IP address:

```
backend_address_pool {
  name            = "${data.terraform_remote_state.rg.vnetnamew}-beap"
  ip_address_list = "[${var.ilbase_virtual_ip}]"
}
```

I have tried it without the `[]` but got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Slight error in syntax was the cause of the problem.  I was trying to using the below:

```
backend_address_pool {
  name            = "${data.terraform_remote_state.rg.vnetnamew}-beap"
  ip_address_list = "[${var.ilbase_virtual_ip}]"
}
```

But it should have been:

```
backend_address_pool {
  name            = "${data.terraform_remote_state.rg.vnetnamew}-beap"
  ip_address_list = ["${var.ilbase_virtual_ip}"]
}
```